# Cytoscape error "Error installing bundle listed in startup.properties..."

Tags: cytoscape

Attempting to install Cytoscape 3.10.0 on RHEL 7.9 and getting the following error when running cytoscape.sh:

Error installing bundle listed in startup.properties with url: mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/org.apache.karaf.features.core/4.3.7 and startlevel: 15

Any suggestions are appreciated. JAVA_HOME is set, etc.

Tried separate versions of Cytoscape. Checked JAVA path. Same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I'm also running into the same issue but on Arch Linux x86_64.

The online documentation suggests that we need Java 11 while for Windows version, it requires Java 17.

So, I tried using both:

Java 11: It throws an error that the executable was compiled with newer version of Java hence Java 11 can't be used to run it.

Java 17: Same error as yours.

I dug into the executable that installs in $PATH and it suggests Java 17!

So, there is definitely some version incompatibility going around.

I also tried with Java 20 but it just hangs on the loading screen.

Hopefully they'll fix the bug soon!

Cheers!

####################### Update ################

**Found a solution:**

Set:

```
export EXTRA_JAVA_OPTS="-Djdk.util.zip.disableZip64ExtraFieldValidation=true"
```

Link to the post: https://community.openhab.org/t/openhab-not-working-with-zulu11-0-20/147910

Comment: Can you both tell me the specific version (and source) for the java 17 you are using?  The referenced link points to openJDK zulu, but we've only tested with the version from adoptium.   It would be useful to know if there is some difference in the versions.

Comment: This just worked for me and I was stuck forever trying to get Cytoscape to open. I had just used it a week ago! Thanks!